# How to restore the install from file upload container in the Joomla back-end admin

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I have the Joomla back-end version 3.10.11 showing empty container in Extension install admin page which it usually should show the area to upload file to install extension/plugin/template and also button to upload file by file upload.

I updated Joomla from 3.9.5 to 3.10.11 using FTP upload on the following Joomla zip files in order to overwrite files:

- Joomla_3.9.x_to_3.9.12
- Joomla_3.10.0 Update
- Joomla_3.10.x_to_3.10.11
  Patch

[File Upload disappearing not showing properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Adzrc.png)

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.